# FlowJS example to loop through files in Angular controller

Tags: javascript, angularjs, flow-js

Does anyone have an example on how to access the `$flow` object in an angularJS controller?  I need to iterate through the files after the end user clicks a submit button before they're uploaded.

I've tried passing the `$flow` object from the front end...

```
<button class="btn btn-success btn-block" type="button" ng-click="ok($flow)">Save Submission</button>
```

And attempting to access it from the back end directly...

```
angular.forEach($scope.$flow.files, function (file, index) {
  // do something
}
```

The $flow object is always undefined.

Answer (score 0):

We have had trouble accessing $flow in $scope as well (though in theory that should work), so I recommend setting the following on the DIV:

```
<div flow-name="uploader.flow" ...> </div>
```

Then you can access in the Angular controller via something like the following:

```
$scope.uploader.flow.files[i].
```